# Trouble understanding NeumannValue and Inactive/Formal PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I read all documentation about the Finite Element Method in Mathematica 10, and I read some questions here, but I'm still unable to properly understand how to use the `NeumanValue` expression to assign a Neumann boundary condition.

Starting with the documentation tutorial "[Solving Partial Differential Equations with Finite Elements](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html)", in the section "Partial Differential Equations and Boundary Conditions" I read:

> The value $g - q u$ prescribes a flux over the outward normal on some part of the boundary: $ \vec{n}\cdot(c\nabla u + \alpha u + \gamma) = g - q u$

Apart some missing vector sign, I think this shoud be a $-\gamma$. With this fix I agree with the following discussion and with the consequent weak form of the PDE.

From this discussion I understand the first `Part` of the `NeumannValue` expression is related to the prescribed outward flux of the quantity inside the `Div` operator.

This leads to the so-called "Formal Partial Differential Equations" section where is pointed that at some time the use of `Inactive` is mandatory to prevent evaluation of differential operators so that `NDSolve` can properly interpret boundary conditions based on `NeumannValue` expression.

It is not so evident (for me) how things are interpreted when `Div` and `NeumannValue` are on the same side of the equation and/or prefixed with a minus sign.

To be more precise, my expectation is that, when `NeumannValue` expression is present on a PDE with also a `Div` operator, after rearranging the equation so that `Div` and `NeumannValue` are on opposite side of the equation and no minus sign is prepended to eiter expression, the first `Part` of the `NeumannValue` expression assign the outward flux of the quantity inside the `Div`. My expectation is that an operator like `Laplacian` should be probably treated as "Div @* Grad".

I'm probably wrong, because I'm unable to translate simple 1-D Poisson equations like these:

```
NDSolveValue[{-u''[x] == 1, u[0] == 0, u'[1] == 1}, u, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

and

```
NDSolveValue[{-u''[x] == 1, u[0] == 0, u'[1] == -1}, u, {x, 0, 1}]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

to use "Formal" notation and inactive `Div`, `Grad`, `Laplacian`, and to understand the following results. For example:

```
NDSolveValue[{Inactivate[-Div[Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] == 
   1 + NeumannValue[1, x == 1], u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> "FiniteElement"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Ok, like the first plot: but why? `NeumannValue` first `Part` assign the flux of the first argument of `Div` whatever sign `Div` has? Maybe...

Moving the minus sign inside the `Div` gives me a result I cannot understand:

```
NDSolveValue[{Inactivate[Div[-Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] == 
   1 + NeumannValue[1, x == 1], u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
 Method -> "FiniteElement"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In my expectation, the differential equation is unchanged, it's still $-u''=1$. Assuming I missed the meaning of `NeumannValue` the Neumann boundary condition can be changed. But the solution plotted appear a solution for $u''=1$...

Moving minus sign inside the `Grad` gives errors (the equation is still $-u_{xx}=1$):

```
NDSolveValue[{Inactivate[Div[Grad[-u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] == 1,
   u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> "FiniteElement"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any help undestanding this matter is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure how `Inactive` interacts with `NDSolve`, but I would have first tried `NDSolveValue[{-Inactivate[Div[Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] == <..>]`, which seems to work.  (Maybe it's a bug?)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm not sure too. But I think an `Inactive` equation should be equivalent to the equation obtained  `Activate`-ing it (except Neumann boundary conditions...).

Comment: @unlikely, I fixed normal flux the sign issue in the documentation. I'll need a little more time to look at the other issue you mention.

Comment: @MichaelE2, basically `NDSolve` sees the things that are inactive (like `Div`, `Grad`) there are a few lines that then parse out the coefficients which are then put into `InitializePDECoefficients`. There simply was no rule for Times[fact_, Grad[...]] which will work in a future version, if fact is `NumberQ`. For all other cases one should use `Dot`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I think you understood the `NeumannValue` documentation/concept quite well. The fact the -Grad does not give the expected result is due to a parsing error in `NDSolve` (which is already fixed in the development version).

```
NDSolveValue[{Inactivate[Div[-Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], Div | Grad] == 
      1 + NeumannValue[1, x == 1], u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "FiniteElement"]
```

You can use:

```
NDSolveValue[{Inactivate[Div[{{-1}}.Grad[u[x], {x}], {x}], 
    Div | Grad] == 
      1 + NeumannValue[1, x == 1], u[0] == 0}, u, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> "FiniteElement"]
Plot[%[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming the problem. What about the minus sign inside the Grad? Will be supported?

Comment: Can you eventually add a skeleton of the current best/safest way to input the equation and Neumann boundary condition?

Comment: @unlikely, I had another look at this. I do not think that I will support the - inside the Inactive[Grad][- u[x]]. The mathematical proper way to specify the diffusion coefficient is via `Inactivate[Div[{{-1}}.Grad[u[x],{x}],{x}],Div|Grad]` The fact that -1*Inactive[Grad] is supported is a convenience but I feel that `Inactive[Grad][-1 u[x],{x}]` would be too much. You can try to convince me other wise, if you want.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to support every possible placement of a scalar multiplier of any PDE coefficent. But, I think it would be useful to expand a bit the documentation to explain what are the "supported" way(s) to input a PDE with Inactive differential operators: after many readings I wasn't able to figure the proper way and what was wrong with my approach.

Comment: @unlikely, agreed and that's something I am working on.